# Creating Pull Request from template and dynamicly instering branch name

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to create Pull Request from templet.md and dynamicly inster branch name that this pr is created for?
I did create an sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
branch=$(git branch --show-current)
filepath="./.github/pull_request_template.md"
filecontent="### [$branch](jira/$branch)"

echo"$filecontent" > $filepath
```

And this is kinda working, but it is updating a pullrequest.md file on branch that I am working on, so this template will not show `$bracnh` when I will create a pr on GH

Is this possible to have one template.md that will be dynamicly updated when pr will be created?